# Media query doesn't execute

Tags: css, media-queries

I've got the following two media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
        .login{
            margin-top: 5%;
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: 204px) {
        .login{
            text-align: center;
            margin-right: 0%;
        }
    }
}
```

- Desktop to mobile
- When commenting out the top query the bottom one executes
- When applying the bottom query styling in the developer tools it works
- I've read this about queries: https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

I must not understand something right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got one too many closing braces which might be messing things up.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .login {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 204px) {
    .login {
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 0%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that's so embarrasing.. Well we all have one of these every now and then :)

Comment: Haha no worries. It happens to all of us, as you say :)

Answer (score 1):

You have added a extra closing braces. Please remove it.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .login {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 204px) {
    .login {
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 0%;
    }
}
```